# A new entity was found through the relationship - only from form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have problem with adding new entity through symfony form.

My db looks like this:
**Document** contains many **Items** every **Item** has **Group**

My form:

```
$builder
    ->add('document', 'entity', array(
        'label' => 'Dokument',
        'class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Document',
        'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) use ($accountId) {
            return $er->createQueryBuilder('d')
                ->join('d.account', 'a')
                ->where('a.id = :account_id')
                ->setParameter('account_id', $accountId);
        },
        'attr' => array(
            'class' => 'form-control',
        )));
```

When I am choosing Document through form i get error

> A new entity was found through the relationship.

But when I am doing it manually (create new `Item` instance, get `Document` from DB and set on `Item`) it works good.

It looks like `Document` instance from form doesn't have connection with `Item` instance and it it recognized as new entity.

My ORM files:

**Document:**

```
AppBundle\Entity\Document:
    type: entity
    table: document
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            unsigned: true
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        documentId:
            type: string
            nullable: true
            length: 50
            fixed: false
            column: document_id
        invoiceId:
            type: integer
            nullable: true
            unsigned: true
            column: invoice_id
        invoiceDate:
            type: datetime
            nullable: true
            column: invoice_date
        modified:
            type: boolean
            nullable: false
            default: '0'
    oneToMany:
        items:
            targetEntity: Item
            mappedBy: document
        children:
            targetEntity: Document
            mappedBy: parent
    manyToOne:
        parent:
            targetEntity: Document
            cascade: {  }
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: null
            joinColumns:
                parent_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
        account:
            targetEntity: Account
            cascade: ['persist']
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: document
            joinColumns:
                account_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**Item:**

```
AppBundle\Entity\Item:
    type: entity
    table: item
    id:
        id:
            type: integer
            nullable: false
            unsigned: true
            id: true
            generator:
                strategy: IDENTITY
    fields:
        quantity:
            type: integer
            nullable: true
            unsigned: true
    manyToOne:
        group:
            targetEntity: Group
            cascade: ['persist']
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: items
            joinColumns:
                group_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
        document:
            targetEntity: Document
            cascade: ['persist']
            mappedBy: null
            inversedBy: item
            joinColumns:
                document_id:
                    referencedColumnName: id
            orphanRemoval: false
    lifecycleCallbacks: {  }
```

**More details**

Working code:

```
/**
 * @return boolean
 */
public function saveItem(Item $item)
{
    try {

        $document = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Document')->find($item->getDocument()->getId());

        $objDate = new \DateTime();
        $item
            ->setDocument($document)
            ->setDateFrom(new \DateTime($item->getDateFrom()))
            ->setDateTo(new \DateTime($item->getDateTo()))
            ->setCreateDate($objDate)
            ->setFreePaperVersion(true)
            ->setAccess(0);

        $this->em->persist($item);
        $this->em->flush();
        return true;
    } catch
    (Exception $ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Not working code:

```
/**
 * @return boolean
 */
public function saveItem(Item $item)
{
    try {
    $objDate = new \DateTime();
        $item
            ->setDateFrom(new \DateTime($item->getDateFrom()))
            ->setDateTo(new \DateTime($item->getDateTo()))
            ->setCreateDate($objDate)
            ->setFreePaperVersion(true)
            ->setAccess(0);

        $this->em->persist($item);
        $this->em->flush();
        return true;
    } catch
    (Exception $ex) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You've `cascade: ['persist']` for `document` relation which persists new entities. The error you have appears when there's a new instance but `cascade` option is not set. It looks like source of the problem is somewhere else, but you've provided too little information to find it.

Comment: Error is appearing when there is no `cascade: ['persist']`, sorry for wrong code. But it proves that, doctrine recognize it as new Entity, because when I add `persist` it goes up in relation hierarchy (recognizing other entities as new one). Until it reach last one - it gives me "Undefined index" error.

Comment: Could you provide the controller code operating on the form and the "manual" operations that you mentioned that work?

Comment: @dragoste I added it to my question

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason for your problem is, that you have a invalid inversedBy definition "item" in "Item" Entity for property "document". Try to change it to items, because the property name "items" in Document Entity.

Do you run bin/console doctrine:schema:validate to ensure to have a valid schema definition ?

Don't forget do execute bin/console doctrine:schema:update --force, to update your database schema.